# How to build custom components in Umbraco?

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

Is it possible to build custom components in Umbraco as you would in standard asp.net? 
I would like to for example make a image upploader. I know how to do that in standard asp.net. I'm concerned how not to break the CMS and extend it with my custom functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to the Umbraco CMS. I would recommend posting your questions on http://our.umbraco.org instead of on Stack Overflow as there are way more people who know the answer hanging out there than there are on Stack Overflow.

To answer your question, if you can build a Web User Control, then you've built a macro for Umbraco! So yes, extensibility is simple. All you need to do know if to either put your user control on a master page (also known as Template in Umbraco, but it's a normal Webforms master page) and it will be picked up.